# How to refresh div without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $("#result").load(window.location.href + " #result");
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
```

this is my script code

```
    <div class="container mb-3">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div id="result">
                <% for (var i = info.length - 1; i < info.length; i++){
                var curTemp = info[i].temp;
                var curGas = info[i].gas; %>
                <h2>temp : <%= curTemp %>C</h2>
                <h2>gas : <%= curGas %>ppm</h2>
                <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

what is problem?
I want to reload that temp and gas values.
but it doesn't work
how to refresh just that div?

Answer (score 0):

You are embedding whole request in the result div, instead, you can try getting required JSON output from ajax request and change the value on HTML so that it will not load the page or create new page request on the server

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
               //get data from ajax request which returns json and output in result div

                $("#result").load(window.location.href + " #result");
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
```